# Django Model Form is not validating the BooleanField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

In my model the validation is not validating for the boolean field, only one time product_field need to be checked , if two time checked raise

```html
product_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)
product_field_count = 0
        for row in range(0,product_field_count):
            if self.data.getlist(f'product_info_set-{row}-product_field'):
                product_field_count += 1
                if product_field_count  <= 1:
                    raise ValidationError(
                        _(
                           " Need to Be Select Once"
                        ))
```

validation error.

Comment: If `product_field_count` is `0`, `range(0,product_field_count)` -> `range(0,0)` -> list(range(0,0))` -> `[]`.    Can you give an example of the `print(self.data)` and `print(product_field)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tidy up the check a little with [`sum(iterable, /, start=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```py
product_field_name_count = sum(
    [
        True
        for row in range(0, product_field_count)
        if self.data.getlist(f"product_info_set-{row}-product_field") is not None
    ]
)

if product_field_name_count > 1:
    raise ValidationError(
        'Only one item of this type may be selected'
    )
```

If you're finding this isn't working as expected, you may want to add `print()` to assure underlying assumptions about where certain variables are correct.

```py
import pprint
pprint.pprint(self)
pprint.pprint(self.__dict__)
pprint.pprint(self.data)
```